# I wrote a function to delete 1st node in circular link list but output is showing infinite times "55 44 33 22 11 99" ,then how can i fix it?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I had checked my display function which is working very well.but my below function isnt working properly. originally list had " 66  55 44 33 22 11"

```
void deleteFOdd(struct Node*head)
{
    struct Node* last=head,*t=head;
    while(last->next!=head)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }

    last->next=t->next;
    head=t->next;
    free(t);
}
```

I am not getting why its printing array after deletion of 1st node, infinite times.

Comment: Your program doesn't print anything. Furthermore, `head=t->next` is pointless, as the variable is about to be destroyed.

Comment: show us your print function.

Comment: You need to return the new head pointer value.  Or the delete function needs to take a pointer to pointer to `struct Node`.

Comment: head=t->next; does not change head add. outside of function . to do so you need to send (struct Node**head). and to update it you needto write:  *head = t->next. but I need a little more code to know that this is the issue.

Comment: Assigning to a parameter has no effect on the thing whose value you passed as the parameter. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: You also have a major problem if you pass a null pointer to that function.

Comment: You can pass a pointer to a function to change *what it is pointing to*. But changing a pointer inside a function will not change the pointer outside of the function. For that you need a pointer to a pointer. `head` should be a pointer to a pointer. Probably.

Comment: Questions on code with unexpected/wrong behaviour benefit very much from providing a [mcve].

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [H.cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10488746/h-cohen) in the comments, changing the `head` parameter locally in the function has no effect on value outside the function. You need to pass the updated head back to the caller somehow. As suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), that could be done either by returning the updated head pointer (which the caller would need to store somewhere, probably in the same variable that is passed to the function), or the function parameter could be changed to a pointer to a pointer to the head.

## Method 1 - returning the new head

```
struct Node* deleteFOdd(struct Node*head)
{
    struct Node* last=head,*t=head;
    while(last->next!=head)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }

    last->next=t->next;
    head=t->next;
    free(t);
    return head;
}
```

There is a bug in the above code as it does not deal with the case of a list containing a single element.  I suggest returning `NULL` in that case.  Also, it would be nice if the function checked if `head` is `NULL` at the start. Here is an amended version:

```
struct Node* deleteFOdd(struct Node*head)
{
    struct Node* last=head,*t=head;
    // optional: deal with NULL list
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }
    while(last->next!=head)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }
    if (last==head)
    {
        // list contained only 1 element
        head=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next=t->next;
        head=t->next;
    }
    free(t);
    return head;
}
```

The caller can call the function as follows:

```
head = deleteFOdd(head);
```

## Method 2 - passing a pointer to the head pointer

The following is based on the amended version above, but uses a pointer to a pointer to pass back the updated head pointer.

```
void deleteFOdd(struct Node** headp)
{
    struct Node* head=*headp;
    struct Node* last=head,*t=head;
    // optional: deal with NULL list
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    while(last->next!=head)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }
    if (last==head)
    {
        // list contained only 1 element
        head=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next=t->next;
        head=t->next;
    }
    free(t);
    *headp = head;
}
```

The caller can call the function as follows:

```
deleteFOdd(&head);
```